# jQuery Fancybox on gallery loaded by Ajax - Issues with grouping

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox-2

I have a list of projects that, when clicked, load some extra text and thumbnails via an ajax request. The images are loaded so, for example:

```
<div class="project-parent"> <!-- Parent is always present -->

<div class="project-media"> <!-- Loaded by Ajax request -->
  <li>
    <a href="full-image.jpg" class="lightbox" data-fancybox-group="group-1234">
      <img src="thumbnail-image.jpg">
    </a>
  <li>
  <li>
    <a href="full-image.jpg" class="lightbox" data-fancybox-group="group-1234">
      <img src="thumbnail-image.jpg">
    </a>
  <li>
</div>

</div>
```

I noticed that to get fancybox (v2.1.5) bound to these new ajax loaded images, I needed to use `jquery on` and have bound it so:

```
$('div.project-parent').on('click', '.lightbox', function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $.fancybox({
        href: $this.attr('href'),
    });
    return false;
});
```

Somehow, I've been unable to find a way to bind fancybox to these images without doing it like this. However, there seems to be a problem then, where the gallery images are not grouped properly (no next/previous navigation), and I think it has something to do with fancybox being called on the parent rather than the `a.lightbox` itself, or am I mistaken?

Any tips greatly appreciated.

Comment: how are the new images loaded (via ajax)? ... manually (on `click`), on page load? the `.load()` method as suggested by @joe below makes much sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be initialising FancyBox in your ajax callback e.g.

```
$('.project-parent').load('images.php', function(){
    $('.lightbox').fancybox();
});
```

If you wanted to do it a similar way to your current code then you could use something like this:

```
$('div.project-parent').on('click', '.lightbox', function () {
    var group = $(this).data('fancybox-group'), images;
    if(group !== undefined){
        images = $('[data-fancybox-group="'+ group +'"]').map(function(){
            return this.href;
        });
    }else{
        images = this.href;   
    }
    $.fancybox( images, {type: 'image'});
    return false;
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/gSL7V/

Comment: Of course... Initialising fancybox in the callback was the way to go. Painfully obvious in hindsight, thank you so much!